# How to Prevent Trimming Trailing Whitepace in VSCode?

Tags: format, editor, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code Version: 1.45.1 on Macos using the built-in Text Editor, editing a `.yml` file.

As soon as I start typing in the file, the editor immediately trims all trailing whitespace from every line in the file. How do I prevent that from happening? Even better would be if there was a single setting to prevent it from making **any automatic edits** to anywhere in the file including adding a final newline, etc.

I tried adding the following to my `settings.json` and restarting VS Code but it didn't seem to have any effect:

```
  "[yml]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": false
  },
```

I also tried with other file extensions including `*.js` and I saw the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was due to the EditorConfig extension -- reconfiguring that solved it.